# Migrates contract with specific account without hard-code address using truffle and Genache

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-migration, migration

Block Builders! I am trying to migrate my two smart contracts using truffle and Genache. I would like to specify the deploying accounts existing locally. However, when I try to migrate the contracts I get error prompt that the provided address being invalid.

Here is my `2_deployed_contracts.js`

```
var Bank = artifacts.require("Bank");
var Client = artifacts.require("Client");

module.exports = function(deployer, accounts) {
  deployer.deploy(Bank, {from: accounts[0], value: 
  web3.utils.toWei("30", "ether")}).then((bank)=>{
    return deployer.deploy(Client, bank.address, {from:accounts[1]});
  });
};
```

and the reported error prompt:

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Bank" -- Provided address "d" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test 
failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted..

at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle- 
deployer/src/deployment.js:364:1
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Only when I hard code the account address at `from` field, the migration success. The accounts variable seems not working like most of the other posts suggested. I could not figure it out why, because I thought truffle would inject accounts variable.

Comment: Would you adding `console.log(accounts[0], accounts[1])` and post the output here?

Comment: And also `console.log(bank.address)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the `accounts` argument at the wrong position (2nd instead of 3rd).

Change this:

```
module.exports = function(deployer, accounts)
```

To this:

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts)
```

P.S.: In the `Provided address "d" is invalid` error, the `d` is probably the first letter in your network name - `development` - as configured in your Truffle configuration file (`truffle-config.js`).

Comment: @Alex: You're welcome. You can find the relevant section in Truffle documentation [here](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#available-accounts).